# Take items from str list (from file) and make into int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to open a file, turn the contents into a string list, then take items from that list at specific positions and make them usable integers. Is there a way to do this?

Where I'm currently at:

```py
#I want to get the 3 and 9 into an x and a y integer.
#File contents:
#Bob
#Male
#43
#3, 9


with open("person.csv", "r") as file:
    mylist = [int(x) for x in file.read().split()]
    print (mylist)
```

Currently getting: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Bob'

EDIT: I know Bob and Male are strings, that's the issue. I need to store both strings and integers in this file and just pull the integers at the bottom (3,9) and then split that specific number into two integers. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: You're trying to convert Bob to a number and that can't happen. Think about what you really want to do and look at where is it in your file.
By the way, you should look into the `csv` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: It is a csv file. I know, Bob is a string and can't be converted, but I can't figure out how to JUST get the items at the 6th point on the list, then split those into two integers. I figured out how to split the list, just not the rest.

Comment: so you already have a list and you just want the value at index 5? use enumerate or set a counter in the loop and when the counter is equall to 5 do something with the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use csv.reader, this will let you pick a delimeter such as "," - don't forget to `import csv` for this.

```
#I want to get the 3 and 9 into an x and a y integer.
#File contents:
#Bob
#Male
#43
#3, 9

import csv

with open("person.csv", "r") as file:
    rows = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=','))
    x, y = rows[3]
    print(x, y)
```

Comment: The 3,9 are both in the same row, that's the issue. Each item in the list has its own row. x(3) and y(9) are updated in the file now and again, separately, then stored when the update is done. At least that's what I need to do. So I want to be able to pull the two numbers as separate integers and then save them in a combo which is later read as a full 2 digit integer.

Comment: @LiterallyMom Okay check it now

Comment: probably cleaner is `x, y = rows[3]`

Comment: AH you are my hero! Thank you. That's exactly what I was trying to do. I apologize for the confusion earlier, it's sometimes hard to verbalize what I'm attempting.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert the string `"Bob"` into an integer. You need to ignore the values that cannot be converted to integers.

Instead of `mylist = [int(x) for x in file.read().split()]`, you should do something like this:

```
mylist = file.read().split()
result = []
for x in mylist:
    try:
        n = int(x)
        result.append(n)
    except ValueError:
        # cannot convert to int
        pass
```

Of course, this won't work right away for `3, 9`.